# Ubuntu 12.04 GUI doesn't load after Virtualbox crash

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, gui

I have Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit installed as a virtual OS in Virtualbox (the host is windows 7).

The Virtualbox data file is on a usb drive that lost connection to the PC while a session was running. Now when I try to start the Ubuntu virtual OS, I get a terminal login screen, but no GUI. When I try to login I get the message

> sh: 1: cannot create /var/run/motd.new: Directory nonexistent

Any suggestions? Can I recover the system?

Comment: Try [this solution](http://superuser.com/questions/236205/how-do-i-recover-files-from-a-corrupt-vdi-file).

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it seems the OS itself is damaged.

Comment: Then I think, you should reinstall the virtual Ubuntu OS

Answer (score -1):

I have same error on my Ubuntu 12.04 Server and I fixed with:

> rm /var/run
>
> mkdir /var/run
>
> reboot